# Flex canvas scrolling problem

Tags: apache-flex, scroll

I have a canvas in my Flex project. It has one child element.

1. I made the element's y property to 500 and a scrrollbar appeared on the canvas.
2. I dragged the scrollbar to bottom to see my element.
3. I moveed element to y = 200
4. After that the scrollbar is still on the same place. How can I update the scrollbar and move it to the top?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, provide the code you're trying to use. 
The following code behaves correctly (scrollbar disappears after clicking the label):

```
<mx:Canvas height="300" width="300">
    <mx:Label id="tl" text="Moved label" y="500" click="tl.y=200;" />
</mx:Canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for sample. It realy help me. I will vote for your answer as soon as I get 15 reputation